# pandas groupby sequential transformations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.DataFrame` that I want to utilize `groupby` and transform several times.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(314)
dti = pd.date_range('2013-01-31', '2015-12-31', freq='M')
quarter = pd.Series(dti[::3], index=dti[::3], name='quarter')
quarter = quarter.reindex(dti).notnull().cumsum()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(dti, quarter))
nda = np.random.randn(len(idx), 3) / 100 + 1.001
df = pd.DataFrame(nda, index=idx, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

`df` looks like this

```
print df.head(12)

                     A         B         C
2013-01-31 1  1.002661  1.008820  1.009523
2013-02-28 1  0.993929  0.991683  1.009867
2013-03-31 1  0.998782  1.004817  0.993274
2013-04-30 2  1.009630  0.998187  0.991681
2013-05-31 2  0.996015  1.008643  1.002915
2013-06-30 2  0.994812  1.017657  1.018382
2013-07-31 3  1.012822  1.012194  0.982339
2013-08-31 3  0.994636  0.993391  1.027641
2013-09-30 3  1.002682  1.002814  1.014214
2013-10-31 4  1.005378  1.002968  0.985704
2013-11-30 4  0.997625  0.991386  0.998687
2013-12-31 4  0.989528  0.996771  1.014305
```

#### Problem

I'm running this code and it feels inefficient.  Is there a method to combine these transformations?

```
df.groupby(level=1).cumprod() \
  .groupby(level=1).shift() \
  .groupby(level=1).fillna(method='bfill')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just occurred to me

#### Solution

use the `apply` method on the `groupby` object. where the function I want to apply is:

```
seq_transform = lambda x: x.cumprod().shift().fillna(method='bfill')
```

then run

```
df.groupby(level=1).apply(seq_transform)
```